# Изменить выбор в ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавляю аудио файлы в `ListBox` нажатием на `Button`. Далее срабатывает `OpenFileDialog` (код ниже). После использую добавленные файлы в `ListBox` для воспроизведения (код ниже). Нажимаю на `button_play` и идет воспроизведение. Вопрос такой. Что изменить, чтобы воспроизведение не выбирало строку по `SelectedIndex`, а по просто выделенной в данный момент курсором строке.

```
private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    label_load.Text = list_catalog.Items.Count.ToString();
}

private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        if (list_catalog.Items.Contains(Vars.GetFileName(file)))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Vars.Files.Add(file);
            list_catalog.Items.Add(Vars.GetFileName(file));
            hello.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void button_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string current = Vars.Files[list_catalog.SelectedIndex];
    Vars.CurrentTrackNumber = list_catalog.SelectedIndex;
    BassLike.Play(current, BassLike.Volume);
    label_time1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
    label_time2.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
    xrewind.Maximum = BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
    xrewind.Value = BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

public static class Vars
{
    public static Form1 Link;

    public static string AppPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    public static List<string> Files = new List<string>();

    public static int CurrentTrackNumber;

    public static string GetFileName(string file)
    {
        string[] tmp = file.Split('\\');
        return tmp[tmp.Length - 1];
    }

    public static void DeleteFile(int num)
    {
        try
        {
            Files.RemoveAt(num);
        }

        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, `SelectedIndex` как раз и есть выделенная в данный момент позиция в `ListBox`

Comment: Проблема в том что когда я сортирую ListBox при помощи             listBox1.Sorted = true, то почему-то при выборе любой музыки играет не та которая должна по названию, а так которая была в этом месте до сортировки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того, как Вы делаете  `list_catalog.Sorted = true`, у Вас сортируется `list_catalog`, а `Vars.Files` остается таким же. Поэтому и выбирается не то, что нужно. Вы можете по имени выбранного в `listBox1` элемента найти элемент с этим же именем в `Vars.Files`:

```
private void button_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     // Изменена одна строка
     string current = Vars.Files.Where(x => x == (string)list_catalog.SelectedItem).Single();
     Vars.CurrentTrackNumber = list_catalog.SelectedIndex;
     BassLike.Play(current, BassLike.Volume);
     label_time1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
     label_time2.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
     xrewind.Maximum = BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
     xrewind.Value = BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
     timer1.Enabled = true;    
}
```

**Update**

`Vars.Files` содержит полные имена файлов, а `list_catalog` - имена без пути. И пытаясь найти значения из `list_catalog`, **равные** значениям из `Vars.Files`, естественно, получили `InvalidOperationException`. Тогда нужно смотреть в какой из строк `Vars.Files` **содержится** строка из `list_catalog`:

```
string current = Vars.Files.Where(x => x.Contains((string)list_catalog.SelectedItem)).Single();
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку - System.InvalidOperationException: "Последовательность не содержит элементов"

Comment: @Eve, Добавьте код класса `Vars`

Comment: Добавил код класса Vars в вопрос

Comment: @Eve, обновил ответ